# Is there a term for the final step an author takes when they "prove" a theme by assigning a reward or tragedy on a character?

Tags: terminology, literary-device

For example, in the tale of the tortoise and the hare the tortoise's victory and the social acceptance it wins would be the step that proves to the reader that committing to being “slow and steady” is beneficial.

I think “climax” would work but I would like to emphasize the judgment aspect of the scene/moment.

Comment: Are you referring to the part of the text at the end that modes the "lesson" explicit?

Comment: @Tsundoku Yes that is a very clear way of putting it.

Comment: The general device of "assigning a reward" or a punishment is *poetic justice*.

Comment: Oh I think that works perfectly. Thanks @henryflower

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you are looking for may be **epimythium**. When a similar lesson is given before the fable, it is called **promythium**. There is a difference between these two terms and the better-known term **moral**. Laura Gibbs's translation of *Aesop's Fable* (Oxford University Press, 2002) gives an example in the context of a discussion of the fable of the ant and the cricket (also know as [The Ant(s) and the Grasshopper](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Three_Hundred_%C3%86sop%27s_Fables/The_Ants_and_the_Grasshopper)). The fable is followed by the following words (italics from the original):

> *This fable depicts lazy, careless people who indulge in foolish pastimes, and therefore lose out.*

Gibbs then explains the difference between the epimythium and a moral:

> Unlike the moral which is fully immersed inside the table (i.e., the witty and vicious words spoken by the ant), the promythium or epimythium draws an explicit link between the world of the fable and the world in which all of us lazy people live. This link between the fable world and our own world is a key element in the fable's didactic function, and a promythium or epimythium explicitly promotes this process of identification.

See also [epimythium](https://www.dbnl.org/tekst/dela012alge01_01/dela012alge01_01_00703.php) in the Algemeen letterkundig lexicon (in Dutch).

---

Edit in response to the question, "How would one use this in a sentence? Would it go like “in the epimythium the author...”, “using epimythium the author implies…" or something else entirely?"

Below are a few examples from scholars discussing how authors use the epimythium.

From *Ethics in Aesop's Fables: The Augustana Collection* by Christos A. Zafiropoulos (Brill, 2017; page 7):

> The last element of a Greek fable, although outside the narrative chain, is the *epimythium* (Nøjgaard calls it *la moralité*). (…) In the *epimythium* the unkown compiler [of the Augustana Collection] has singled out the point that he we wanted to draw from the fable. In this sense, the *epimythium* is a later addition to the fable and sometimes an abrupt one.

From *The Anthropology of Wisdom Literature* by Wanda Ostrowska Kaufmann and Hanna W. Kaufman (Greenwood Publishing, 1996; page 8):

> In this case there seems to be a discrepancy between the moral expressed in the epimythium and the tale, which tells of a man who saves a friend falsely accused of a murder by claiming responsibility for the crime.

Comment: How would one use this in a sentence? Would it go like “in the epimythium the author...”, “using epimythium the author implies…" or something else entirely?

Answer (score 2):

For fables and texts with fairly explicit messages, I would call that the *moral*.

I don't know if there is another, more explicit, word for the point in the story where the author emphasizes the moral. You could say *the author reveals the moral by ...*